# Python Convert Strings in a List to Integers Based on Order

Tags: list, python-3.x

Given this list of strings:

```
list=['foo','foo','foo','bar','bar','baz','baz','baz']
```

I'd like to get a list of the corresponding numbers as if this were an index with tied ranks like this:

```
numbers=[0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could the list look like: `['foo','bar','foo','baz']` ?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: You mean the output? For that, I need the numbers as shown. Another example: list=['d','d','d','r','r','t] would need to be: numbers=[0,0,0,1,1,2]

Comment: @DylanLawrence is asking whether you could see a given value repeated with different values between the repetitions. That is, is `['d', 'r', 'd']` possible, and if so, is the output `[0, 1, 2]` or `[0, 1, 0]`?

Comment: Sorry, it would be 0,1,0, but the list will be in order for me.

Comment: @DanceParty2: Okay. Either answer I gave below should work then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the strings are already grouped (all repeated strings are consecutive), the lowest overhead way to do this is with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
from itertools import groupby

numbers = [i for i, (_, g) in enumerate(groupby(mylist)) for _ in g]
```

This just groups the entries in `mylist` (`list` is a terrible name for a variable, shadowing the `list` constructor), and produces `i` (the 0-up count of groups seen so far) once for each entry in the group (we don't even care what the values are, thus `for _ in g` to indicate the `_` is unimportant).

If repeated values might be non-consecutive, but should have the same group number (that is, `['d', 'f', 'd']` might occur, and should produce `[0, 1, 0]` rather than `[0, 1, 2]`), you'd use a different approach (which would also work with the consecutive only case, but requires persistent and growing state that the `groupby` approach avoids):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import count

# If key seen already, returns value, otherwise, returns next unused integer group number
grouptracker = defaultdict(count().__next__)  # .next on Py2

numbers = [grouptracker[x] for x in mylist]
```

Or to one-line it for fun and inscrutability (don't actually do this):

```
numbers = list(map(defaultdict(count().__next__).__getitem__, mylist))
```

Comment: To clarify on the "state" cost, for the `groupby` approach, the memory required beyond that necessarily used for `numbers` and `mylist` is fixed; `mylist` could hold one element or 10 million elements, and one group or 10 million groups, and the memory required above and beyond that used for `mylist` and `numbers` wouldn't change. The `defaultdict` solution, by contrast, would require additional memory proportionate to the number of unique groups in `mylist`.